# What is the biological relevance of RIPPLE phase in membranes?

Tags: biophysics, cell-membrane, lipids

I was reading about *ripple phase* in bilayer lipid membranes which is described [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.4139.pdf) as a meta-stable state between *lamellar tilted crystalline* and *lamellar fluid* state. It is also known that ripple phase exists just below the *phase transition temperature* **$T_m$**. The figure below is from this [article](http://www.pressesagro.be/base/text/v14n4/719.pdf).

[image]

<strike>I have 2 questions here:</strike>

1) Is ripple phase a stationary structure or does it propagate in space as a travelling wave? (Since they have crystalline structures inbuilt will the *fluidy defect* propagate?)

2) Secondly and more importantly will ripple phase gets exhibited above transition temperature $T_m$ if the lipid interacts with some molecules like protein etc?

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

***What can be the possible biological significance of Ripple phase in membranes?*** Will formation of ripple in membrane initiate any relevant processes, since membrane curvature itself is changing? I will be really helpful for any resources related to this.

I am citing an experimental biological work related to Hsp12 protein interaction with DMPG membrane in yeast which reports ripple phenomenon well above the usual transition temperature. Paper [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1097276510005836).

---

**NOTE:** I was initially confused about whether to post this in biology.SE or physics.SE. I got more tags here. So posting it here.

Comment: Mmmm odd. Anyway, this post is indeed Bio, physics and also chemistry related. What I would do is go to the respective sites, enter their chat and ask if it's on topic there. Cross posting is not OK, so I'd reckon if Physics accepts it, I can either migrate or you can repost and delete it here. Physical might be your best bet, but Chemistry might as well.

Comment: @AliceD I have modified the question a little bit and given a bounty. Do you want to have a look now?